# Use gssapi with Microsoft office outlook.

Tags: windows, email-server, outlook, gssapi

Currently in windows computer I have installed [Kerberos for Windows](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/kfw-4.0/kfw-4.0.html).

This allowed me to use sso with Thunderbird against a Cyrus IMAP.

Thunderbird has the option of using GSSAPI.

Is possible to configure Microsoft office outlook to access via GSSAPI?.

The idea is to keep the sso we got in the Outlook desktop client.

It occurs to me that there may be a gateway.

I know [DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/) but is specific to Exchange servers.

I appreciate any help with this setup!.

Comment: What version of Outlook?

Comment: Microsoft Office Outlook 2003 (11.5608.5606)